# VBA conversion Office 2007 to Office 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a function in an Access 2007 database, which has been working fine until my PC was upgraded to Office 2010.  The procedure is below and the offending line is that where 'originalFolder' is set:

```
Function ExportToSharePoint()
Dim oFs As New FileSystemObject
Dim originalFolder As Folder
Dim destinationPath As String
Dim ofile As file
Dim XLApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlwb As Excel.Workbook
Dim strFileName As String
Dim oFolder As String
oFolder = "//chs114file1/dovpasres/Public/Script/InfoCentre/Delays"
Set oFs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set XLApp = New Excel.Application
    Kill "K:\Public\Script\InfoCentre\Delays\*.xlk"
    Set originalFolder = oFs.GetFolder(oFolder)  
    destinationPath = "https://companyname.sharepoint.com/PRR/Documents/"

    For Each ofile In originalFolder.Files

        strFileName = oFs.GetFileName(ofile)

            Set xlwb = XLApp.Workbooks.Open(ofile)
            xlwb.SaveAs (destinationPath + strFileName)

    Next

xlwb.Close True
XLApp.Quit
Set xlwb = Nothing
Set XLApp = Nothing

End Function
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Error 13: data type mismatch

I'm mystified as this is a string, as required?

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Have you checked for missing references? Debugged? Compacted and repaired?

Comment: Thanks for your responses...The error I'm getting is 'Error 13: data type mismatch', I have checked all references and they're okay, I've also compacted and repaired several times!  Permissions are fine too, I can do this copy manually.

Comment: Did you try changing the data type for the `originalFolder` variable from `Folder` to `variant`?

Comment: Superb!  That's fixed it, thank you.
I did think about doing that earlier in the process but I prefer not to use variants to keep memory use low.  Should have tried it afterall!
Many thanks again.

Comment: Added as an answer, with a bit of elaboration.

Comment: What about `Dim originalFolder As IWshRuntimeLibrary.Folder`? You do want a folder returned, do you not?

Comment: Was there a bitness change, i.e. 32-64?

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft documentation lists the [`GetFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1xtf7ta%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) return type as being [`Folder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c87day3%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), but I suspect your problem is being caused by mixing late binding (via `CreateObject`) with early binding (via the strongly-typed Folder variable).
Either import the reference to avoid the `CreateObject` call, or change the type to a variant, or perhaps object:

```
Dim originalFolder As variant
```

Comment: If a folder is not returned when a folder is needed, isn't it better that it fail?

Comment: You should be able to check for a null value to detect when `GetFolder` fails (which you'd have to do regardless which form you use).

Comment: I think it would be better to skip `Set oFs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` when it already exists and is referenced as evidenced by `Dim oFs As New FileSystemObject`. Strong typing helps prevent errors, it should be possible to check though the filesystemobject that the folder exists and then assign it.

Comment: I agree; strong typing helps avoid errors (and has Intellisense benefits) - that was the first part of my suggestion, i.e. 'import the reference'.

Comment: It is already available or the code would not compile. The first line is `Dim oFs As New FileSystemObject` It would fail immediately, not on the line that assigns the folder if the reference did not exist. There is more to this problem than would seem, I reckon, or why does it work, in spite of miscoding in 2007 but not in 2010?

Comment: Correct; all I was saying was, pick one or the other.  Clearly early binding is a better option, although I didn't highlight that in my answer. On the 2007->2010 issue, it's a bit cloudier; it seems likely that it would be due to an internal change in the new vbscript engine, but documentation on the differences is sparse.

Comment: The code works for me in 2010. I think that folder must be defined elsewhere, that is why I am concerned.